# How to stall angular execution until JSON has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asynchronous, synchronous

I've got an angular app that needs to load app config data from some JSON, this is wrapped up in a service, which gets injected into controllers. The problem is that I need the controllers to wait until the json has been successfully loaded. In other words, load it synchronously. I want to make a request for this json file and have the app do *nothing* until we get it back. I don't know what the "proper angular" way to do this is, suggestions?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the UI thread, roughly speaking, so synchronous Ajax calls make the UI unresponsive. Best to use asynchronous calls instead, and allow your controllers to be in a "loading" state.

Comment: could manually bootstrap angular once you have the data instead of having it auto initialize using `ng-app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `angular.bootstrap()` to initialise the app.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
//declare the rest of myApp, e.g. myApp.controller(...

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON('/api/my-app/config', function(data) {
        //do whatever you wish with `data`
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('my-app'), ['myApp']);
    });        
});
```

NOTE:

- Feel free to use any other method to fetch your config JSON, does not have to be `jQuery.getJSON()`
- Instead of two nested callbacks in `angular.element(document).ready()` and the AJAX call,
  consider using promises, so that they may happen simultaneously
- This code is untested, you probably will have to tweak it a little

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. In this case it doesn't make sense for the app to even be bootstrapped before that data comes down the wire.

Comment: hmm, when I bootstrap it this way, the route doesn't seem to execute, any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Never mind, just had to move the code block lower. =)

Comment: @IainDuncan what do you mean by move it lower - `var myApp = angular.module...` comes first?

Comment: Yeah, I had to move the code to the bottom of the file below the first module definition, then it was fine!